# PDO errorInfo Full List and specifically error code 1451

Tags: php, pdo, error-handling

I'm working on a big database were i created links between primary and foreign keys. I'm using "**Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.10**" and my codes are built with the PDO methods.

While i'm testing the delete functionality, i'm getting this message from the errorInfo:

```
    Array ( 
[0] => 23000 
[1] => 1451 
[2] => Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`#DBNAME#`.`#TABLE1-NAME#`, CONSTRAINT `#CONSTRAINT-NAME#` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `#TABLE2-NAME#` (`id`)) ) Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I know that error is caused by trying to delete a records with a primary key related to other foreign keys. What i was wondering about is the error code number, can i assume always when i receive this number **1451** that the error is between primary and foreign key, or could it be linked to some other errors as well?

And i tried searching for a full list of errorInfo codes with its error message with no success. Can someone let me know if this list existe somewhere on the internet. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A List of MySQL Errors with its Messages can be found here: [Error List](https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-error-codes-and-messages)
Following this list your error code is only for this specific message.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the link of the error list

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-error-codes/ is better